# How we are able to import third party packages like express with both import syntax (es6) as well as require (commonjs) in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-modules, commonjs

Out of curiosity I opened express package and inside there was `module.exports`....but still we can import with es6 syntax. But when it comes to modules that I export as commonjs module, and try to import it with `import` statement, node throws error. Very confusing for a beginner like me. I need some clarification.

Comment: Did you read https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs? It should answer all your questions. If you have a specific problem (such as the example setup where you get an error), please ask a specific question about that.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, it helped me. One more doubt is that, so if we set `"type" : "module"` in package.json, then do all modules become ES modules outside of node_modules folder? Therefore I can't use module.exports and import for same same file, instead I have to use import-export statements only, right?

Comment: Yes, with `"type": "module"`, all `.js` files in that package become ES modules. (If you `require` them, I guess you get an error). And yes, you cannot (and absolutely should not) combine `module.exports` with `import` declarations in the same file. However, you can use dynamic `import()` in a CommonJS module.